# Data not displaying (default state not showing) when clicking on "Home" Navigation Menu Item

Tags: java, android, api, navigation, blogger

I built a `Blogger` Java android application by parsing self created `BloggerAPI` using `Retrofit and Gson` Libraries.

I created three navigation menu items that are used to display blogs using the following mentioned items' names as labels:

1. ***Home***
2. **Android**
3. **iOS**

Out of these three items 2nd and 3rd option worked correctly but *when I clicked on **Home** the default data was not displayed, it displayed other items' data every time except "Home (default data)".*

Please help me how I can resolve this or how to implement this. Thanks a lot!

**Code MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    Toolbar mToolBar;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    PostAdapter postAdapter;
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    String token = "";
    SpinKitView progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.postList);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_menu);
        progress = findViewById(R.id.spin_kit);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        postAdapter = new PostAdapter(this, items);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

        setUpToolbar();

        navigationItemSelectListener();

        getData();
    }

    private void setUpToolbar() {
        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToolBar = findViewById(R.id.mainActivity_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolBar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.getChildAt(0).setSelected(true);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    private void navigationItemSelectListener() {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not set it to checked state.
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    getData();  ////// here data isn't displayed when click on "Home" //////
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_android:
                    Call<PostList> androidPostList = BloggerAPI.getService().getAndroidPostList();
                    labelPostListCall(androidPostList, "Android");
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_ios:
                    Call<PostList> iosPostList = BloggerAPI.getService().getIOSPostList();
                    labelPostListCall(iosPostList, "iOS");
                    return true;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + item.getItemId());
            }
        });
    }

    private void labelPostListCall(Call<PostList> postListCall, String labelName) {
        postListCall.enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onResponse
                    (@NonNull Call<PostList> call, @NonNull Response<PostList> response) {
                PostList list = response.body();
                try {
                    if (list != null) {
                        items.clear();
                        items.addAll(list.getItems());
                        postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, labelName + " Post(s) Displayed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    items.clear();
                    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No " + labelName + " Post(s)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<PostList> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("MainActivity", "onFailure: " + t);
            }
        });
    }

    private void getData() {
        String url = BloggerAPI.mBaseUrl + "?key=" + BloggerAPI.key;

        if (token != "") {
            url = url + "&pageToken=" + token; // append token
        }
        if (token == null) {
            return;
        }

        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Call<PostList> postListCall = BloggerAPI.getService().getPostList(url);
        postListCall.enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<PostList> call, @NonNull Response<PostList> response) {
                PostList list = response.body();
                try {
                    if (list != null) {
                        items.clear();
                        token = list.getNextPageToken();
                        items.addAll(list.getItems());
                        postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    items.clear();
                    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Data: Empty List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<PostList> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("MainActivity", "onFailure: " + t);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Problem occurred at that Point:**

```
case R.id.nav_home:
     getData();
     return true;
```

Comment: Does onResponse is called with the correct data (in getData() method? Is it parsed correctly?

Comment: @gioravered Yes, called with the correct data and parsed correctly.